# PowerShell: Restart Service By Executable Name

Tags: windows, scripting, powershell, windows-services

all

I implemented my first PowerShell script, that does some setup, sets registry keys and at then end needs to restart services. The problem is that I have only have name of the executable, but not service name. Restart-Service can work only with name of the service. Googling (well Binging also) around didn't give me much result.

**I was wondering whether there is a way to restart service by executable name?**

I know that I can get process by executable name, but just killing the process and starting it again is NOT good choice, since service Start/Stop functions are not called and it may not work properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using wmi and do something like this:

```
(gwmi win32_service | ?{$_.pathname -match "\\executable.exe "}) | Restart-Service
```

Comment: You cannot pipe WMI service instances to the Restart-Service cmdlet. The objects are not of the same type.

Comment: @Shay: Try the piping.. Do a great job!

Comment: The comments I made on @Shay's solution about the matching also apply to this solution. This will match executables: "MyExecutable.exe", "AnotherExecutable.exe" "executable.exec.exe", etc.. `"\\executable.exe\b"` would be better, but "\executable.exe.new.exe" would also match it (I know, unlikely).

Comment: @Rynant - The OP probably knows the executable and its path or even the params etc. OP can specify the whole. And you don't seem to know how `svchost.exe` works. Services don't use that as executable path.

Comment: I know what `svchost.exe` is, and that you would not be restarting services by matching the `svchost.exe` process. There are services that use it as the executable path. I get 119 services if I run: `gwmi win32_service -filter "PathName like '%svchost.exe%'"`. My point was that `$chost.exe%` will match `svchost.exe`

Comment: Yes, the OP can specify a better match, but the OP says he only has the name of the executable. `-match 'executable.exe'` could match other executables. I simply want the OP to be aware of this.

Comment: @Rynant - You are right about svchost.exe. My understanding was wrong. Anyway, I have updated my match string, which should be more "safe"

Comment: Ouch, I can see what went wrong. I was thinking of "A" and writing "B", thinking one step ahead, wrong phrasing!! What I wanted to say is that Restart-Service cannot restart (stop,start) services on remote computers. If you add the ComputerName parameter in gwmi and pipe to Restart-Service you're basically restrting the service on your local machine! (provided the remote service exist locally). Pipeing WMI service instance to Restart-Service works because the Name parameter accept pipeline input.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "PathName LIKE '%PartOfTheName%'" -ComputerName PC1 | Foreach-Object{
    $_.StopService()
    $_.StartService()   
}
```

Comment: What if there are multiple services with the same .exe. I have multiple services that use sqlservr.exe. Also, what if there is a service that uses "AnotherExename.exe" (the "%" wildcard will cause it to match); unlikely, but possible.

Comment: You can extend the code to deal with multiple objects, I'll update it in a minute. If you want to match parts of the service name enclose the string in %.

Comment: I wasn't saying that the match should be less strict, but more strict. What if there was a service called "chost.exe"? '%chost.exe' would also match 'svchost.exe'. Also the `PathName` parameter includes aguments (eg. 'msiexec.exe /V'). '%\chost.exe%' would be better, but not 100% foolproof since it would match 'chost.exec.exe' I know I'm being a pain, but I'm just trying to handle all cases :-P

Comment: @Ryhant, I'm able to extract the image name with the following command: Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service | Foreach-Object { Split-Path -Leaf ($_.PathName -split('\s\-|/'))[0].Trim('"')}
. It it works for you as well we can write a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using WMI:

```
$process = Get-Process sqlservr| select -ExpandProperty Id

Get-WmiObject win32_Service| 
    where {$process -contains $_.ProcessId}|
    foreach {Restart-Service $_.Name}
```

**Edit:** Changed script to restart service, not just stop it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#set by logic to determine if the service will restart or not
 $global:ServerWillRestart=$true 

#can be found using the name column of Get-services cmdlet
 $serviceName="Set name of the service" 
if($global:ServerWillRestart){
     $service =Get-Service | where{ $_.Name -eq $serviceName}
do{
    Write-output "The service $ServiceName will is being stopped"
    Stop-Service $service
    Start-Sleep -s 2
}
while($service.WaitForStatus("Stopped"))

do{
    Write-Output "The service $ServiceName will is being started"
    Start-Service $service
    Start-Sleep -s 2
}
while($service.WaitForStatus("Running"))
```